# AWS EC2 Ubuntu 14.04 instance clock running 12 minutes ahead

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, system

We are using Ubuntu 14.04 (LTS) on Amazon EC2 m4.xlarge instances. It seems the instance clock is running 12 minutes ahead of the current time.

I am using python shell to check time by running this command

```
import datetime; datetime.datetime.utcnow()
```

I was wondering if there is any solution to this issue that does not involve an instance restart.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must edit the `chrony` configuration file to add a server entry for the Amazon Time Sync Service.

**To configure your instance to use the Amazon Time Sync Service**

1. Connect to your instance and use apt to install the `chrony` package.

> ubuntu:~$ sudo apt install chrony

**Note**

If necessary, update your instance first by running `sudo apt update`.

2. Open the `/etc/chrony/chrony.conf` file using a text editor (such as `vim` or `nano`). Add the following line before any other server or pool statements that are already present in the file, and save your changes:

> server 169.254.169.123 prefer iburst

3. Restart the `chrony` service.

> ubuntu:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/chrony restart
>
> [ ok ] Restarting chrony (via systemctl): chrony.service.

4. [ ok ] Restarting `chrony` (via systemctl): `chrony.service`.

> ubuntu:~$ chronyc sources -v

```
 210 Number of sources = 7

  .-- Source mode  '^' = server, '=' = peer, '#' = local clock.
 / .- Source state '*' = current synced, '+' = combined , '-' = not combined,
| /   '?' = unreachable, 'x' = time may be in error, '~' = time too variable.
||                                                 .- xxxx [ yyyy ] +/- zzzz
||      Reachability register (octal) -.           |  xxxx = adjusted offset,
||      Log2(Polling interval) --.      |          |  yyyy = measured offset,
||                                \     |          |  zzzz = estimated error.
||                                 |    |           \
MS Name/IP address         Stratum Poll Reach LastRx Last sample
===============================================================================
^* 169.254.169.123               3   6    17    12    +15us[  +57us] +/-  320us
^- tbag.heanet.ie                1   6    17    13  -3488us[-3446us] +/- 1779us
^- ec2-12-34-231-12.eu-west-     2   6    17    13   +893us[ +935us] +/- 7710us
^? 2a05:d018:c43:e312:ce77:6     0   6     0   10y     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^? 2a05:d018:d34:9000:d8c6:5     0   6     0   10y     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^? tshirt.heanet.ie              0   6     0   10y     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^? bray.walcz.net                0   6     0   10y     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
```

In the output that's returned, ^* indicates the preferred time source.

5. Verify the time synchronization metrics that are reported by `chrony`.

> ubuntu:~$ chronyc tracking

```
Reference ID    : 169.254.169.123 (169.254.169.123)
Stratum         : 4
Ref time (UTC)  : Wed Nov 29 07:41:57 2017
System time     : 0.000000011 seconds slow of NTP time
Last offset     : +0.000041659 seconds
RMS offset      : 0.000041659 seconds
Frequency       : 10.141 ppm slow
Residual freq   : +7.557 ppm
Skew            : 2.329 ppm
Root delay      : 0.000544 seconds
Root dispersion : 0.000631 seconds
Update interval : 2.0 seconds
Leap status     : Normal
```